# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80040154

Tags: .net

When running my script i get error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-C000-000000000049} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154.

What is the cause of this?

The platform is running on x86

This is not a duplicate. The other one didn't have an accepted answer so and it involves Microsoft office, in which mine doesn't so it's not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem in Opening Word 2010 using Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125962/problem-in-opening-word-2010-using-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: (Exception from HRESULT: **0x80040154** (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). - class not registered is the issue.

Comment: Well the other one didn't have an accepted answer so and it involves Microsoft office, in which mine doesn't so it's not,

Comment: `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` is the CLSID for MS Word. It's not the same value as in the OP, but it's close. MS defines some GUIDs manually - this one ending in 46 is such a case. In fact there are many COM related GUIDs that end with `-0000-0000-C000-000000000046`. I suspect that the GUID in the OP is somehow a mangled GUID: either typed into SO wrong or messed up on the system where the script is running. I also suspect that something, under the covers, is trying to access WORD. Search the registry for "000209FF' and report back where it was found.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the relevant part of your script, any answer is conjecture.

1 Your script is attempting to instantiate a class that doesn't exist on the server.

2 If the class is implemented in a DLL or EXE, that file must be registered with Windows on the server.